# Expand large array and select elements in JQ

Tags: json, select, bigdata, jq

This may just not be possible due to how conceptually streaming/filtering JSON works, but let's suppose I have something like the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "account_1",
    "type": "account"
  },
  {
    "name": "account_2",
    "type": "account"
  },
  {
    "name": "user_1",
    "type": "user"
  },
  {
    "name": "user_2",
    "type": "user"
  }
]
```

And now I want to print out only the user objects.

I know I can filter to just the streaming type entities with something like this:

```
cat file.json | jq --stream 'select(.[0][1] == "type" and .[1] == "user" | .)'
```

Which would produce:

```
[
  [
    2,
    "type"
  ],
  "user"
]
[
  [
    3,
    "type"
  ],
  "user"
]
```

Is there any way I can print out the parent objects of those types instead of the type entities?  E.g. I'd like to get out:

```
[
  {
    "name": "user_1",
    "type": "user"
  },
  {
    "name": "user_2",
    "type": "user"
  }
]
```

Without streaming, this is a pretty straightforward exercise.  E.g.:

```
cat file.json | jq '.[] | select(.type=="user")'
```

In reality the actual input file is around 5GB, so I need to use streaming input, but I can't seem to get the jq syntax right with `--stream` enabled.  E.g.

```
cat file.json | jq --stream '.[] | select(.type=="user")'
```

Produces:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:3): Cannot index array with string "type"
jq: error (at <stdin>:5): Cannot index array with string "type"
...
```

(edited to include desired output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just truncate the top-level array.

```sh
jq -n --stream 'fromstream(1 | truncate_stream(inputs)) | select(.type == "user")'
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FbXdyy_xkI)</sup>

<sup>jqplay does not support the --stream option, so the above demo has the output of --stream as the JSON input.</sup>

Comment: To produce the expected result as per the Q, one could pipe the output of the above to `jq -s .`; the alternative of wrapping the filter in square brackets([...]) might be acceptable if the resultant array is not too large.